# How to create a custom tree chart style layout (with sharp angles) vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

Wasn't sure if this should be on the github as an issue so I thought this was the best starting point.

I am looking to create a mind-map/network/diagram with this kind of layout:
[image: example layout]
Is this possible out of the box with vis.js networks?
the tail end seems to be a left to right hierarchical layout which is definitely a thing (though having sub sections configured differently might be harder).

Failing that has it been done in any examples you've seen

or

where should I get started with implementing something myself

Comment: You should "get started" by reading the official [**vis.js documentation for timelines**](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/), and then coming back to StackOverflow with a specific problem that you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for the quick comment, Im not looking at timelines because they are dom based and I would like this to be canvas based. (I also have no use for the timeline features and use for all of the network ones instead)
would you suggest this on the git issues page instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way how one can create such a thing – using hidden nodes.

Create a network with nodes and edges like this:

```
nodes:'[
     {id:1,label:"start", x:0,  y:0}
    ,{id:2,label:"angle", x:0,  y:100, hidden:true}
    ,{id:3,label:"angle", x:100,y:100, hidden:true}
    ,{id:4,label:"finish",x:100,y:200}
]

edges:[
     {from:1, to:2}
    ,{from:2, to:3}
    ,{from:3, to:4}
]'
```

and you will get this:

[image]

This is of'course not very nice to create "fake" nodes (for instance, this is not nicely manipulatable – all those angles will change so you'd better forbid moving nodes at all) but at least allows to create a static image like you want.

PS yeap, you have to do some calculations if you want to generate such layouts automatically.

PPS here's a fiddle for you to tweak this further: https://jsfiddle.net/tjyvLbns/11/ I've already changed some options to make it look closer to what you need:

[image]

Comment: sweet! I am well past this issue, ended up using a curve that was very close to right angle from the presets but this is an awesome starter for anyone else looking to do this.